# converting from byte array to drawable image gives corrupt image: Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, sockets

I am converting an image into a byte array. Sending it over a socket, then once it is through the socket, I need to convert it back to a drawable, png, or any type of image that I can use as the background of an image button. **The problem is that when I either convert into a byte array, or from an array into a drawable, the file is getting corrupted.**

I am getting my original image from the last installed app on my phone as follows and then I am saving it to a file on the phone so I can check that at this point the image file is successfully captured (and it is. Nothing is corrupt at this point):

```
final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);
Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(ai);
BitmapDrawable bitmapIcon = (BitmapDrawable)icon;

FileOutputStream fosIcon = context.openFileOutput(applicationName + ".png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

bitmapIcon.getBitmap().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fosIcon);
InputStream inputStream = context.openFileInput(applicationName + ".png");

Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);


// GET FILE DIRECTORY

File imageFile = new File(context.getFilesDir(), applicationName + ".png");
```

Now I am converting this bitmap to a byte array to send over the socket:

```
// get bitmap image in bytes to send

        int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
        Log.d("tag_name", "Number of Bytes" + bytes);

        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
        bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

        byte[] array = buffer.array();
        Log.d("tag_name", "array" + array);
        int start=0;
        int len=array.length;
        Log.d("tag_name", "length" + len);


new SendToClient(array, applicationName, len, start).execute();
```

At this point I know my file is successfully getting saved as this image:

[image]

Then, in SendToClient, I am using DataOutputStream to send over the array. I am not posting this code, because I have tested that sending the data is not where the problem occurs. If I don't send the byte array, and convert from the byte array back to a drawable in this same activity, it is also corrupt.

Here is how I convert from an array back to a drawable after using DataInputStream to read the array that was sent:

```
YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(array, ImageFormat.NV21, 100, 100, null);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 100, 100), 80, baos);
        byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();

        // Convert to Bitmap
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
        Log.d("tag_name", "bmp" + bmp);

        // convert bitmap to drawable
        final Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bmp);
```

The reason I am first compressing to a JPEG is because if I only used BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray, then I would get "bmp = null", converting to JPEG first was the only solution I found where I could get a bitmap that wasn't null, but now my image is corrupt. This is what Drawable d looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following code,

> Convert Bitmap to ByteArray.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.myImage);
ByteArrayOutputStream opstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, opstream);
byte[] bytArray = opstream.toByteArray();
```

> Convert ByteArray to Bitmap.

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytArray, 0, bytArray.length);
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgv1);
img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This may helps you.